# Why does this simple SSI not render the include?

Tags: html, ssi

I'm trying to add ssi to a more complex project without success. I've whittled it down to the simplest possible and it still does not work. I'm obviously missing something very simple, but what?

OS: Windows 10 Pro, build 19045.2251

Server:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.46 (Win64)
Apache Lounge VS16 Server built:   Oct  2 2020 11:45:39
```

relevant http.conf lines not commented out:

```
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so 
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
```

http.conf contains:

```
...
<Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs">
...
    Options +Includes
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
...
```

C:\Apache24\htdocs contents:

```
index.html
bogus.shtml
```

index.html:

```
<html><body>
<!--#include file="bogus.shtml"  -->
<h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

bogus.shtml:

```
<h4>Nothing to see here</h4>
```

Yet `http://localhost` renders only `It works!`

Comment: Not sure if `"One disadvantage to this approach is that if you wanted to add SSI directives to an existing page, you would have to change the name of that page, and all links to that page, in order to give it a .shtml extension, so that those directives would be executed."` is relevant but you have `index.html` rather than `index.shtml`

Comment: If it is perhaps [XBitHack](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_include.html#xbithack) might be of interest

Comment: Thanks. Tried creating a new file (`waldo.html`) with the contents of `index.html` to no avail. Plus, since I'm on Windoze, the execute bit can't help.

Comment: have you tried `waldo.shtml` though?

Comment: Doh! I had not connected that dot. Does this mean that `.html` files cannot include `.html` files? That there needs to be a differentiation of extensions for ssi to work?

Comment: I've not looked at SSI for years (circa 1999) but I believe .shtml extension is required. Whether or not you can fudge things with `rewrites` I don't know

Comment: I've been working in PHP frameworks for nearly as long so includes were never an issue. Just trying to rework a very ugly homeowners assoc. site got me wondering about DRY issues. Think I'll make ssi work to solve that problem. Thanks for the help. I'll accept your answer if you like.